# Is Google docs "Getting started with ARC" still available somewhere?

Tags: google-chrome-arc

Before this stackoverflow group started there was a Google docs link "Getting started with ARC" available at https://docs.google.com/document/d/13DtdjQQ4aRuCOegnPlLfk05-9J4vjuWMsUgvEdUbAs8/edit

Is this document still available somewhere?

Comment: the doc itself reminds you to: https://developer.chrome.com/apps/getstarted_arc

Comment: I've seen that, but the original document showed a more comprehensive explanation of the settings etc.